# Spring Actuator Metrics preserve "dot" in tags

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer, spring-actuator

I'm creating tags in my metrics exporter, in this way:

```
  metrics:
    export:
      elastic:
        host: "xx"
        index: "metricbeat-k8s-apps"
        user-name: "elastic"
        password: "xx"
        step: 30s
        connect-timeout: 10s
    tags:
      cluster: ${CLUSTER}
      kubernetes.pod.name: ${POD_NAME}
      kubernetes.namespace: ${POD_NAMESPACE}
```

But I don't know why "kubernetes.pod.name" is converted to "kubernetes_pod_name", how can I preserve the dots ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word separator in Micrometer is 'dot' ([see docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_naming_meters)), according to the [Elastic naming conventions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/current/event-conventions.html), the word separator is 'underscore' in Elastic. In Micrometer, every registry has a `NamingConvention`. For Elastic, it is [`ElasticNamingConvention`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/00b1b25fab27475f6cf3f7303d0609fcee60beba/implementations/micrometer-registry-elastic/src/main/java/io/micrometer/elastic/ElasticNamingConvention.java).

As you can [see](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/00b1b25fab27475f6cf3f7303d0609fcee60beba/implementations/micrometer-registry-elastic/src/main/java/io/micrometer/elastic/ElasticNamingConvention.java#L36-L38) in that class, the default naming convention is `snake_case`:

```java
public ElasticNamingConvention() {
    this(NamingConvention.snakeCase);
}
```

You can see how `ElasticMeterRegistry` [uses this naming convention](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/00b1b25fab27475f6cf3f7303d0609fcee60beba/implementations/micrometer-registry-elastic/src/main/java/io/micrometer/elastic/ElasticMeterRegistry.java#L145), but you can provide your own, please [check the docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_naming_meters).